# SAS: print the name related to the most little value

Tags: sas, min

I'm a beginner in SAS and i have difficulties with this exercice:
[I have a very simple table with 2 columns and three lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeFUV.png)

I try to find the request that will return me the name of the most little people (so it must return titi)
All what I found is to return the most little size (157) but i don't want this, I want the name related to the most little value!
Could you help me please?
Larapa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL `having` clause is a good one for this. SAS will automatically summarize the data and merge it back to the original table, giving you one a one-line table with the name of the smallest value of `taille`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        select nom
        from have
        having taille = min(taille)
    ;
quit;
```

Here are some other ways you can do it:

Using `PROC MEANS`:

```
proc means data=have noprint;
    id nom;
    output out=want 
        min(taille) = min_taille;
run;
```

Using sort and a data step to keep only the first observation:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by taille;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    if(_N_ = 1);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I thought about the third possibility but I think it's not very optimized (you need to sort your data first)...